# Live Server Renders Page Different Than Local Server

Tags: html, css, server, rendering, local

I have a problem that has me stumped and I'm hoping someone here can help me solve it. I designed a new site using Sublime and am having problems with one file(page) that looks great on Sublime, but is screwed up when I put it on the live server.

From Sublime it renders perfectly on all web browsers, so I don't think has anything to do with it. I suspect that maybe it has something to do with the Cascading part of CSS. But, I don't know how to determine that.

Anyhow, here's the the code involved: http://portabledogpotty.com/dog-potties.html

The first section is the HTML and the second section is the CSS file. Any help would be very greatly appreciated!

Sam

Comment: Could you specify how it is "screwed up"? Does it look like the CSS is missing entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a table only for the header **SAVE EXTRA MONEY WITH OUR VALUE PACKS! **, try to put it as a th in the table for packs.

I see that just using the chrome element inspector.

Grettings

Comment: Thanks! Am trying that out now.

Comment: I'm still not sure what was going on, but by recoding the table and corresponding css the problem was resolved. Still is strange how it looks fine on Sublime and not on a live host. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem :D have a nice day